# Ng-class and comparing values from different firebase arrays

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I'm currently extremely stumped on how to achieve the following -

I'm trying to use ng-class within ng-repeat to conditionally apply a bootstrap background-color class.

Simple enough and works great when I input a static value to compare to (in this case "25") -

In the controller. Data is coming from firebase. The data is stuctured like so -

```
"myDatabase": { "someNumber":"12" }

"myOtherDatabase": { "compNumber":"30" }


var ref = new Firebase(my-first-firebase-url); 
$scope.data = $firebase(ref);

var ref2 = new Firebase(my-second-firebase-url);
$scope.data2 =$firebase(ref2);
```

In the View -

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'bg-info' : item.someNumber > 25}"> {{item.someNumber}} </div>
```

However I would like to make the comparison value pulled dynamically from a SEPERATE firebase object that I'm updating with a separate $watch function. Obviously the following doesn't work but how can I achieve the intended results...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'bg-info' : item.someNumber > data2.compNumber}"> {{item.someNumber}} </div>
```

any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: what happens if you put `item.someNumber > data2.compNumber` inside the div like `{{item.someNumber > data2.compNumber}}` @UglyNford

Comment: {{item.someNumber}} doesn't seem to be available outside of the ng-repeat <div>

Comment: I meant inside `ng-repeat` like : `<div ng-repeat="item in data"> {{item.someNumber > data2.compNumber}} </div>
`

Comment: It returns "false" even when I know the expression should evaluate to "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function in the $scope to generate the classes to be inserted in the HTML. I always prefer to have this kind of logic in the JS part, and in this specific case is specially important because you need to first convert your value from string to number.

Here is a small example:

```js
angular.module('webapp', [])
    .controller('dummyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.data = [{
                value: '1'
            },
            {
                value: '40'
            },
            {
                value: '20'
            },
            {
                value: '10'
            },
            {
                value: '50'
            },
            {
                value: '20'
            }
        ];

        $scope.threshold = 30;

        $scope.getClass = function(item) {
            return {
                'bg-info': Number(item.value) > $scope.threshold
            };
        };
    }]);
```

```css
.bg-info { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="webapp">
        <head>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="webapp">
            <div ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
                <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="getClass(item)"> {{item.value}}</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is extremely helpful. Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction. I was hoping the answer would be a little less involved but overall I'm pretty sure I can adapt your suggest to my code. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, I usually provide a working example with my answers because I feel like its the easier way to transmit my thoughts on the question. Sorry if I came across as too intrusive.

Comment: Not at all!! I'm a total beginner and have been learning by doing so seeing how professionals accomplish these types of things is extremely helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry to be a bother.. I'm still a bit stumped on how to make $scope.threshold dynamically pulled from firebase. I've incorporated your code successfully in my controller and removed the logic from my HTML. It works great when I set $scope.threshold to have a static value of 30.

Comment: I think I just got it working by assigning a value to $scope.threshold by using "child_added" and a snapshot function.. hopefully its not too much of a hack job...